# Convert the value to specific date format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following date in B cell. Actually this is not in the date format.

```
2015-11-01-01.13.34.737000
```

that has to be changed into the following format:

```
11/01/2015 01:13:34 AM
```

I'm not so familiar in excel formulas. Can anyone help me to bring the expected output? Actually, I tried changing the date format using format cells but no luck and also tried some excel formulas.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I tried changing the date format using format cells but no luck and also tried some excel formulas."_ Post what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: First, I just tried replacing "-" with "/" by SUBSTITUTE formula. Then "." to ":". Finally trying to skip last 6 digit.

Comment: That's a good start.  Then just extract the time and date portion using `LEFT` and `MID` and add the two together.

Comment: If I replace the first two occurrences of "-" with "/ and third occurrence with " " and next two occurrences to be ":". Then finally, remove the last 6 digit. Will it be the good idea or what would be the better solution?

Comment: Define "good". If you just need it to work, does it really matter? Or is this going to be used over and over again and you have some criterion of speed or elegance to meet?

Comment: Actually, it is going to be worked for around 38 thousands of record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original value is in cell A1, then as written, this works:

`= MID(A1, 6, 2 ) & "/" & MID(A1, 9, 2) & "/" & LEFT(A1, 4) & " " & SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, 12, 8), ".", ":") & " AM"`

If you need the formula to 12-hour time and append `AM` or `PM`, then obviously you need to extract that 2 digits of the input value and check whether it's `>= 12`, append the right string, and change the hour before you output it. By the time you've understood what the above is doing, you may begin to see how you could do that. However, since it's a bit more complex, here:

`= MID(A1, 6, 2 ) & "/" & MID(A1, 9, 2) & "/" & LEFT(A1, 4) & " " & RIGHT("0" & MOD(MID(A1, 12, 2) - 1, 12) + 1, 2) & ":" & SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, 15, 5), ".", ":") & IF(NUMBERVALUE( MID(A1, 12, 2) ) < 12, " AM", " PM")`

The `MOD` is needed to wrap around after 12 hours, and the add/subtract `1` acrobatics are because we write hours from 1 to 12, not 0 to 11. The `right("0" & foo, 2)` bit simply ensures that 1-digit numbers are 0-padded to 2 digits. This *seems* to work, but I didn't test it totally exhaustively.

Comment: This is really awesome. It works charm. I'm just going through your formulas and explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome. Of course, some of the opaque syntax and repetition here could be alleviated by e.g. putting the cells in a Excel table, factoring out repeated expressions to intermediate columns, etc. - always good if you're going to leave formulae like this in production! But I didn't include such embellishments unless it's shown that they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," ",3),"-","/"),".",":"),":",".",3)
```

The above converts your original string into a string with this format:

```
2015/11/01 01:13:34.737000
```

The double unary at the beginning then converts that string to a real Excel date/time which can be formatted however you wish.

Comment: And then what? They need to format as custom date/time, presumably. How do we do 12-hour times there? Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the brevity of this, and getting the value into a real date/time is always preferable, but it's a bit cryptic. :)

Comment: @underscore_d  It produces a real date/time which can be formatted however you wish.  For 12-hour times, yhou would format it as `mm-dd-yyyy h:mm AM/PM`